# System Monitor, Settings and other windows have no decoration

Tags: unity, 13.10, compiz, gtk, window

I've been using Ubuntu 13.10 for a reasonable amount of time now, and I have never encountered this issue before. One day the frame (the part with the close, minimize and maximize buttons) just disappeared on some programs. The x button moved to the right but I can't resize the window and I can only move it if I alt drag. Here are some screenshots (I have hidden the user column in system monitor to hide my name): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MVQb.jpg. I have tried uninstalling compizconfig-settings-manager and I've reset Unity. Thanks!

Edit: I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling gnome-control-center and gnome-system-monitor which seem to be the programs having issues.